# Django console message: GET /%7B HTTP/1.1

Tags: html, django, templates, django-templates, django-1.11

Between once a second and 10 times a second I get the following message displayed on the console:

> "GET /%7B HTTP/1.1" 404 26453

After running `python manage.py runserver`

I believe it has some relation to my carousel image strip because it stops the timer animation from scrolling across the top of the image to indicate how long left the image will be shown for until it moves on to the next one:

```
{% for image in images %}
    <img src="/static/images/background-carousel.png" style="z-index: -1">
        <li data-masterspeed="1500" data-slotamount="7" data-transition="zoomout">
            <div class="tp-caption customin customout" data-captionhidden="on"
                         data-customin="x:0;
                                 y:100;
                                 z:0;
                                 rotationX:0;
                                 rotationY:0;
                                 rotationZ:0;
                                 scaleX:1;
                                 scaleY:3;
                                 skewX:0;
                                 skewY:0;
                                 opacity:0;
                                 transformPerspective:600;
                                 transformOrigin:0% 0%;"
                         data-customout="x:0;
                                 y:0;
                                 z:0;
                                 rotationX:0;
                                 rotationY:0;
                                 rotationZ:0;
                                 scaleX:0.75;
                                 scaleY:0.75;
                                 skewX:0;
                                 skewY:0;
                                 opacity:0;
                                 transformPerspective:600;"
                         data-easing="Power4.easeOut"
                         data-endeasing="Power1.easeIn"
                         data-endspeed="300"
                         data-speed="750"

                         style="z-index: 9;
                                 text-align:center;">
        <img alt="{{ image.title }}" class="boff_white" data-bgfit="cover"
                             data-bgposition="center center" data-bgrepeat="no-repeat"
                             src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ image.image }}"
                             style="width: {{ image.width }}; height: {{ image.height }}"/></center>

        </div>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

After the above code there are some more images hard-coded.

I am wondering what it means and how it can be fixed?

I am currently taking over development on the website from someone else (the for loop scope of code is the only bit that is mine).

- Using Django 1.11 (cannot upgrade this)

Thank you.

Check answers for solution!

But what does the message mean?

Edit:

From here: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp %7B is a `{` ASCII encoding reference...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a `{#` without a closing `#}` in a `src="{% static 'images/carousel...' %}"` in the hard-coded section.

`%7B` is the ASCII encoding reference (see here: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp)